# Uploading an avatar for a user when he/she registers

Tags: php, sql

I'm creating a link sharing website and I want the user that registers to upload an avatar and use that avatar throughout the website.

I got so far that the user can register but can't find a way for him/her to have an avatar.

Here I have the signup.php file so that you can see what I mean.

```
<?php
    include 'connect.php';
    include 'header.php';

    echo '<h3>Register</h3><br />';

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
    {
      /*the form hasn't been posted yet, display it
  note that the action="" will cause the form to post to the same page it is on */

    echo '<form method="post" action="">
    <b>Username: </b><input type="text" name="user_name" /><br/><br/>
    <b>Password: </b><input type="password" name="user_pass"><br/><br/>
    <b>Confirm assword: </b><input type="password" name="user_pass_check"><br/>      <br/>
    <b>E-mail: </b><input type="email" name="user_email"><br/><br/>

          ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
          ///////// must I use <input type="file"> here???? /////////
          ///////// and how do I put it in the database???? /////////
          /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

    <input type="submit" value="Join" />
 </form>';
    }
    else
    {
    /* so, the form has been posted, we'll process the data in three steps:
    1.  Check the data
    2.  Let the user refill the wrong fields (if necessary)
    3.  Save the data 
*/
$errors = array(); /* declare the array for later use */

if(isset($_POST['user_name']))
{
    //the user name exists
    if(!ctype_alnum($_POST['user_name']))
    {
        $errors[] = 'The username can only contain letters and digits.';
    }
    if(strlen($_POST['user_name']) > 30)
    {
        $errors[] = 'The username cannot be longer than 30 characters.';
    }
}
else
{
    $errors[] = 'The username field must not be empty.';
}


if(isset($_POST['user_pass']))
{
    if($_POST['user_pass'] != $_POST['user_pass_check'])
    {
        $errors[] = 'The two passwords did not match.';
    }
}
else
{
    $errors[] = 'The password field cannot be empty.';
}

if(!empty($errors)) 

    /*check for an empty array, if there are errors, they're in this array (note the !     operator)*/
{
    echo 'Uh-oh.. a couple of fields are not filled in correctly..<br /><br />';
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($errors as $key => $value) /* walk through the array so all the errors get displayed */
    {
        echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>'; /* this generates a nice error list */
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
else
{



    //the form has been posted without, so save it
    //notice the use of mysql_real_escape_string, keep everything safe!
    //also notice the sha1 function which hashes the password
    $sql = "INSERT INTO
                users(user_name, user_pass, user_email ,user_date, user_level)
            VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']) . "',
                   '" . sha1($_POST['user_pass']) . "',
                   '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_email']) . "',
                    NOW(),
                    0)";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if(!$result)
    {
        //something went wrong, display the error
        echo 'Something went wrong while registering. Please try again   later.';
        //echo mysql_error(); //debugging purposes, uncomment when needed
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Succesfully registered. You can now <a href="signin.php">sign  in</a> and start sharing links.';
    }
}
}

include 'footer.php';
?>
```

and here is my database files so you can maybe tell me how to add the avatar in the database

```
CREATE TABLE users (  
user_id     INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
user_name   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
user_pass   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,  
user_email  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,  
user_date   DATETIME NOT NULL,  
user_level  INT(8) NOT NULL,  
UNIQUE INDEX user_name_unique (user_name),  
PRIMARY KEY (user_id)  
);

CREATE TABLE categories (  
cat_id          INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
cat_name        VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,  
cat_description     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,  
UNIQUE INDEX cat_name_unique (cat_name),  
PRIMARY KEY (cat_id)  
);

CREATE TABLE topics (  
topic_id        INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
topic_subject       VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,  
topic_date      DATETIME NOT NULL,  
topic_cat       INT(8) NOT NULL,  
topic_by        INT(8) NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (topic_id)  
); 

CREATE TABLE posts (  
post_id         INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
post_content        TEXT NOT NULL,  
post_date       DATETIME NOT NULL,  
post_topic      INT(8) NOT NULL,  
post_by     INT(8) NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (post_id)  
);
```

How can I add the avatar in the databse when the user registers?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you really don't want to do this at the registration form. Create an "edit profile" page for this.

Secondly, without starting that discussion again, you might not want to store the avatar image in the database, but rather store it as a file and store the filename in your user / profile table (or use the username or ID as filename).

So, the steps to take:

1. A logged in user uploads a picture to its profile (using an )
2. You store the image in a directory, say `/images/avatars/$userid.jpg`
3. Whenever anyone views the profile of a user, you insert an `<img src="/images/avatars/$userid.jpg">` tag

Or, for storing in the database:

1. A logged in user uploads a picture to its profile (using an )
2. You determine the $filename, say $random.$extension
3. You store the image in a directory, say `/images/avatars/$filename`
4. Update the user row, by setting avatarurl = $filename
5. Whenever anyone views the profile of a user, you retreive the filename for the avatar of that user and insert an `<img src="/images/avatars/$filename">` tag

The second approach has the advantage that it's independent on file extension, and you can 'hide' the files by using a random ID for each image, so malicious visitors can't guess and harvest all avatars.

Answer (score 0):

You don't save the actual image into the database, only the filename.

Then you can simply add a file selection element to your form, and use it to upload the image and save the filename in the database.

I personally like to do this with uploadify (http://www.uploadify.com/), which makes the process a little nicer for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Plupload is another example of uploading files to a server.  I've used uploadify, swfupload and some others I can't remember.  Plupload was the best one out there.

[plupload](http://www.plupload.com/)